# Rename JEE project

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, rename

I'm working on a JavaEE project, I already have the skeleton of an old project. All i have done is rename the project, packages and change the name in the project file (.project). But now when i'm trying to run, it returns error in the browser "The requested resource is not available". I've checked the web.xml and added a new jsp in vain it doesn't work. In the browser's address, it gives me the old name of the project(http://localhost:8061/smsgate/). I've tried a lot to fix the problem. what can i do? Is there any other file that i have to update and write in the new name? Please give me your ideas (knowing that i have to use that old project)

Comment: did you rename your project by right click on project -> refactor -> rename ?

Comment: no i renamed it directly in my workspace and in the project file (.project)

Comment: this is a bad way to rename a project. Try importing the project then right click -> refactor -> rename

Comment: I just tried what you've said, finally i can get the new project's name in the browser's address but still no jsp displayed

Comment: We need more information about your projet, such as the web.xml file and so on

Comment: It's working Thank's a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do Project -> Clean in your workspace by selecting your current project. Also if using maven then right click your project and do maven -> clean.
Manually go to your target directory of your ear module and shift-delete everything inside your target and then rebuild your project to form new ear.
if you have configured the web.xml properly then strike your app url. Also ctrl+shift+delete your browser history and then check.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a new project using a maven archetype, just type in the console:

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

It will show you a list of available archetypes from the web, just choose one of them, for JEE6/JEE7 you could choose among:

```
1019: remote -> org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:webapp-javaee6 (Archetype for a web application using Java EE 6.)
1020: remote -> org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:webapp-javaee7 (Archetype for a web application using Java EE 7.)
```

If you agree with me, just type:
1019 or 1020 according to your needs and answer the questions like:

```
projectId:your-project-name
groupdId:com.yourdomain.reverse
version:1.0
```